# Group array by values in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array, which contains data as follows:

```
 Array (
[google.com] => Array
    (
        [youseo.com] => 1,
        [seo.com] => 1,
        [linkbuilding.com] => 0,
        [seo556.com] => 1,
    )

[youtube.com] => Array
    (
        [youseo.com] => 0,
        [seo.com] => 0,
        [linkbuilding.com] => 0,
        [seo556.com] => 1,
    )

[facebook.com] => Array
    (
        [youseo.com] => 0,
        [seo.com] => 1,
        [linkbuilding.com] => 1,
        [seo556.com] => 0,
    )
  )
```

And I need to populate new array and count value of url:

```
Array 
 (
 [google.com] => 3
 [youtube.com] => 1
 [facebook.com] => 2
 )
```

Please any help for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `array_values` and `array_sum`:

```
$counts = array();
foreach ($array as $page_name => $record)
    $counts[$page_name] = array_sum(array_values($record));
```

But that's assuming the values can only be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

If `$a` is your array:

```
$counts = array();
foreach ($a as $page_name => $page)
{
    foreach ($page as $name => $value)
    {
        $counts[$page_name] += $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `array_map` with `array_sum`

```
$result = array_map(function($el) {
    return array_sum($el);
}, $data);
```